# Execute a bash script with a shortcut on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shortcuts

I've a problem, I'm trying to execute a script whith shortcut on Ubuntu but it doesn't work:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNrjH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGaj5.png)

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not useful. What happens? What do you want to happen? Does the script do what you want when invoked in a terminal? If you think the shortcut doesn't work at all, how do you know? Please respond by [edit]ing the question. Put `date >/tmp/testfile` just after the shebang, hit the shortcut and check `/tmp/testfile`; *maybe* the script runs without a terminal.